# Inverse parent-child relationship in Visio E-R Model

Tags: parent-child, visio, cardinality, entity-relationship, multiplicity

I was trying to make a simple E-R model with Microsoft Visio 2010.
The problem is, I want a "one-to-many" relationship between the "RealEstateCompanies" entity and the "Agents" entity. However, I am not able to do this. As is shown in the first picture, I can only change the multiplicity for the "RealEstateCompany" entity.

[image: problem]

I don't understand why Visio makes the "RealEstateCompanies" entity as the child entity by default and I can't reverse the parent-child relationship between the two entities (as is shown in the picture below).

[image: problem]

Please help, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can I change cardinality notation at both ends? Or just reverse the parent-child relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Visio determines parent/child relationship by direction of the connection (connections in Visio are directed, and the directions are defined by how the things are actually connected, not by the arrow ends).

Try simply deleting your connection, and then drawing it again in correct direction (you need to draw the relationship **FROM** "RealEstateCompanies" **TO** "Agents")

Comment: Believe it or not, changing the comparative positions of these entities worked! Drawing from "RealEstateCompanies" to "Agents" made no difference... anyway, thanks for your help!